Invalid property 'authorizationRedirectStrategy' of bean class org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter
in webapp applicantion non spring-boot and with spring securtity 5, I did minimale config of oauth2 openid connect :
<sec:http create-session="stateless" auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/oauth**" access="permitAll" />
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />            
        <sec:oauth2-login 
                  authorized-client-repository-ref="authorizedClientRepository" />            
        <sec:logout logout-url="/logout" invalidate-session="true" success-handler-ref="customSuccessLogoutHandler" />
</sec:http>

The client registration (of courses, urls in provider are filled)
        <sec:client-registration registration-id="test"
                             client-id="xxx"
                             client-secret="xxx"
                             authorization-grant-type="authorization_code"
                             redirect-uri="https://test"
                             scope="openid,roles,profile"
                             client-name="test"
                             provider-id="fid"/>
                  <sec:provider provider-id="fid"
                  issuer-uri=""
                  authorization-uri=""
                  token-uri=""
                  user-info-uri=""
                  user-info-authentication-method="header"
                  user-info-user-name-attribute="sub"
                  jwk-set-uri=""/>
    </sec:client-registrations>

<bean id="authorizedClientService"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.InMemoryOAuth2AuthorizedClientService"
        autowire="constructor"/>

    <bean id="authorizedClientRepository"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.AuthenticatedPrincipalOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository">
        <constructor-arg ref="authorizedClientService"/>
    </bean>

in my pom, I have spring necessary lib and :
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.5</version>
        </dependency>

in starting tomcat, I have the error :
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'authorizationRedirectStrategy' of bean class [org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter]: Bean property 'authorizationRedirectStrategy' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.createNotWritablePropertyException(BeanWrapperImpl.java:243)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.processLocalProperty(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:432)

Any idea please

FYI: Spring Security OAuth2 is end of life since 2022. You should use Spring Security 5 or 6 instead.
